# expected value with sampling with replacement and without replacement

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $S$ be a set of $c$ elements sampled uniformly at random from the set $\{a_{1}, a_{2}, \cdots, a_{t}\}$, and $0 \leq \delta \leq 1$.

Let $X$ be a random variable that counts the number of elements in $S$ with rank strictly less than $\lfloor \delta t \rfloor$. Prove that $\delta c - \frac{2c}{t} \leq E[X] \leq \delta k$ in the case of both sampling without replacement and with replacement.

I know how to do the with replacement case but stuck at without replacement case